# Google Cloud SQL import unknown error

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Instance: db-n1-standard-1 - 200gig - us-central - Second Generation

I have a mysql database on an external production server I'm trying to get into Google Cloud SQL.  It's approx 130 gigs (uncompressed).

I dumped the file - moved to google storage - ran the import.  I got a notification during the import with a "unknown error".  I was watching the storage meter, and it kept increasing so it appeared as though it was still processing.

It apparently picked itself back up and completed successfully.

If I go into the "Operations" tab for the instance, it makes no mention of the "error" notification (that is still available with a "RETRY" option from the notifications area at the top of the page), but instead says "Import from gs://[bucket_name]/mysqld.sql.gz succeeded."

I exported the binlog changes and ran it in the same fashion.  Another error in notification but it appeared to continue. Operations tab again has a successful message with no mention of any errors.

This is a large dataset.  Not sure how to validate that all is well, or which notification I should trust..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry :(

There's a known issue with the status timing out in the notification panel and showing an error. You can trust the status in the operation list.

Comment: For the record, I went through and ran a mysql checksum table against every table and compared all the results.. It was a long night, but everything checked out ok.

Comment: If you're ever in doubt, trust the API results: If you are using gcloud you can use the `gcloud sql operations list`, `gcloud sql operations describe` and `gcloud sql operations wait` to interact directly with the Cloud SQL API.

Comment: ^ This should really be in the Gcloud/CloudSQL documentation. "Just so ya know, every successful database import will generate an error message, don't be alarmed and like waste a day verifying the import or anything."

Comment: The answer you are commenting on is over a year old and the issue reported in this question was fixed a while back as well. It sounds like you are running into a different issue which perhaps warrants a separate question?

Comment: I found this question because I got the same error on an import and couldn't track down what could have caused the error. Don't get me wrong I appreciate your answer very much. Concise, to the point, useful. I'm using your suggested cloudsql operations describe command right now. I was just snarkily suggesting that the cloudsql documentation could really be improved. For example. a note like "After a restore, make sure to run a manual copy before creating a read replica" that would have saved me a couple hours yesterday.

Comment: I'm still getting the same (false) error in the notification tab when dumping from Google Cloud SQL to Google Storage.

Comment: @Vadim The spurious error message in the Cloud Console still occurs on long-running Cloud SQL imports and exports as of February 2020.