# Importing data into Cloud SQL instance error Invalid Credentials

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to import my database using a bucket, but Im getting an error about Invalid credentials, this a second generation of google cloud, after review the operations tab of my instance it looks like the importing data still running. Im not sure if this process still working. Does anybody have idea about how to solve this problem?

Regards

Comment: I think you have to post some code.

Comment: Hi Glenn, I'm using the Console.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36323107/google-cloud-sql-import-unknown-error, this a known issue.